# Custom Renderer CornerRadius for Frame on UWP in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

How to CornerRadius for 1, 2 or 3 Corners of the Frame on UWP with Xamarin Forms ?

Example:
Example Custom CornerRadius for Frame

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Here is my code to custom and that works fine
//In PCL, I created CustomFrame class:
    public class CustomFrame : Frame
    {
    }

// In UWP, I created MyFrameRenderer class:
    [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomFrame), typeof(MyFrameRenderer))]
    namespace DeliveryApp.UWP  \* Your namespace *\
    {
     public class MyFrameRenderer : FrameRenderer
     {
     protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Frame> e)
      {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
         Control.CornerRadius = new Windows.UI.Xaml.CornerRadius(50, 0, 50, 0);
        }
      }
     }
   }

//Then I use MyFrameRenderer in xaml file: <. . 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DeliveryApp.Helper;assembly=DeliveryApp" />

    <local:CustomFrame />
```

Comment: Could you please give a review comment for this